# How to crop an image in Android

Tags: android, crop

I want choose a image from the gallery and crop that. I can choose the picture but I can't crop that yet.
That is my code I have yet:

```
public static final int PICK_IMAGE = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    
    if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && data != null){
        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        cropIntent.setData(data.getData());
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 450);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 350);
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, 1);
    }else if(requestCode == 1){
        Log.d("resultCode", String.valueOf(resultCode));
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap bitmap = extras.getParcelable("data");
        ImageView test = findViewById(R.id.test);
        test.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        test.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

When I start the app I can select a picture. After that my application closes because the *data* in this line: `Bundle extras = data.getExtras();` returns null. And before that the *resultCode* is 0 which means it canceled. How I can fix that?

Comment: Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`. While a few devices might have a pre-installed app that honors your desired `Intent`, that `Intent` is undocumented and unsupported. There are [a couple dozen image-cropping libraries available for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45?sort=created) -- I strongly recommend that you use one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can crop an image using an `onActivityResult()`.
This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w06OnGwhh4I&ab_channel=AndroidCoding) shows how to set it up properly with `setOnClickListener()`.

Don't forget to set the `implementation` in your `build.gradle`:

```
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.+'
```

Good luck! :)